# TypeError: Cannot read property 'legend' of undefined | Angular + ng2-charts

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'legend' of undefined` when trying to display example data for a chartjs chart in angular.

I've tried using different examples or chart types, but it keeps throwing this error.

HTML:

```
<div class="chartwrapper">
  <canvas baseChart class="chart"
          [datasets]="arbarChartData"
          [labels]="arbarChartLabels"
          [options]="arbarChartOptions"
          [legend]="arbarChartLegend"
          [chartType]="arbarChartType">
  </canvas>
</div>
```

TS:

```
public arbarChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
public arbarChartType = 'bar';
public arbarChartLegend = true;
public arbarChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
  {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'}
];
```

Comment: try legend=true instead of [legend]="arbarChartLegend"

Comment: tried that, same error

Comment: remove   `[legend]="arbarChartLegend"` from html. In **TS**  `arbarChartOptions: any = {
      legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
          fontColor: 'black'
        }
}`

Comment: That worked, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Can I add it as answer?

Comment: Can you accept my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `[legend]="arbarChartLegend"` from your html.

In TS, `arbarChartOptions: any = { legend: { display: true, labels: { fontColor: 'black' } }`

Comment: I solved my problem by installing `ng2-charts-x` package which is used to solve some problems of `ng2-chart`.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was enough to initialise empty `arbarChartOptions` like:

```
public arbarChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
public arbarChartType = 'bar';
public arbarChartLegend = true;
public arbarChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
  {data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A'},
  {data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B'}
];
public arbarChartOptions: ChartOptions = {}
```

to solve the error